# Unable to evaluate against a specific value

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I am having trouble thinking of the correct logic on how to go about this. I have a function that accepts two types of switches:

- `-Add`
- `-Remove`

```
Function Test-Bool {
        
    Param (
        # Input Parameters
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   HelpMessage='Enter. Workflow. Name.')]
        [Alias('OMB','MailBox')]
        [string]$Workflow,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [Alias('EDIPI','DisplayName')]
        [string[]]$UserName

    )

      DynamicParam {
        if ($Workflow -ne $null -and $UserName -ne $null) {
          $parameterAttribute = [System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute]@{
              ParameterSetName = "AddingMembers"
              Mandatory = $false
          }

          $attributeCollection = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]]::new()
          $attributeCollection.Add($parameterAttribute)

          $dynParam1 = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new(
            'Add', [switch], $attributeCollection
          )

          $paramDictionary = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
          $paramDictionary.Add('Add', $dynParam1)
          

          $parameterAttribute1 = [System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute]@{
              ParameterSetName = "RemovingMembers"
              Mandatory = $false
          }

          $attributeCollection1 = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]]::new()
          $attributeCollection1.Add($parameterAttribute1)

          $dynParam11 = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new(
            'Remove', [switch], $attributeCollection1
          )

          $paramDictionary.Add('Remove', $dynParam11)
          return $paramDictionary

        }
      }      
    Begin {
        $ABool = {
            'Add Block'
            $Bool = Read-Host -Prompt 'Adding or Removing Member(s)'
                if ($Bool.ToLower() -like 'a*') {
                    $true
                }
                else {
                    Break;
                }
        }
        $RBool = {
            'Remove Block'
            $Bool = Read-Host -Prompt 'Adding or Removing Member(s)'
                if ($Bool.ToLower() -like 'r*') {
                    $true
                }
                else {
                    Break;
                }
        }   
        if ($PSBoundParameters['Add'].IsPresent) { [bool]$Add = $true }
        elseif ($PSBoundParameters['Remove'].IsPresent) { [bool]$Remove = $true }
        elseif (-not$PSBoundParameters['Add'].IsPresent) { $Add = & $ABool }
        elseif (-not$PSBoundParameters['Remove'].IsPresent) { $Remove = & $RBool }
    }
    Process {
        if ($Add) {       
            "Add was selected"
        }
        if ($Remove) {
            "Remove was selected"
        }
    }
}
```

I can run it several ways:

- `Test-Bool -Workflow spg -UserName a -Add` - **works**
- `Test-Bool -Workflow spg -UserName a -Remove` - **works**
- `Test-Bool -Workflow spg`

  - Should ask to remove or add: Typing **Add**, **works**.
  - Typing **Remove**, does *not* work.

Which makes sense, because `elseif (-not$PSBoundParameters['Add'].IsPresent) { $Add = & $ABool }` is evaluated first and when asked, *Remove* is typed in which throws it into the `else` block making it *Break/Exit*.

---

**QUESTION:**
What can I change to make `$Remove` be evaluated to true and vise-versa when `Add` is typed (*to make `$Add` True*)?

*I honestly confused myself so much that I just decided to post here instead of attempting to figure this out on my own.*

Comment: Are `-Add` and `-Remove` supposed to be mutually exclusive?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I'm not sure what you mean by that? It's either one or the other, if that's what you're asking for?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking, thanks :) Is there a particular reason you want to use dynamic params for this?

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. No reason, just fanciness (:

Comment: Although I think it should be possible to have an easier dynamic syntax for this (see [Hierarchical Parameter Scripting #13746](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13746)), for now it is probably best to use [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameter_sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Parameter Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameter_sets) instead:

```
Function Test-Bool {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Undecided')]
    Param (
        # Input Parameters
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   HelpMessage='Enter. Workflow. Name.')]
        [Alias('OMB','MailBox')]
        [string]$Workflow,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [Alias('EDIPI','DisplayName')]
        [string[]]$UserName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Add')]
        [switch]$Add,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Remove')]
        [switch]$Remove
    )

    begin {
        $action = if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Undecided'){
            $answer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Adding or Removing Member(s)?'
            if($answer -like 'a*'){
                'Add'
            }
            elseif($answer -like 'r*') {
                'Remove'
            }
            else {
                throw 'Invalid option provided'
            }
        }
        else {
            $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
        }

        # $action now contains either 'Add' or 'Remove'
        $actionBlock = @{
            'Add'    = { <# code to add user to workflow #> }
            'Remove' = { <# code to remove user from workflow #> }
        }[$action]
    }

    process {
        # if/else statements no longer needed, $actionBlock contains the correct scriptblock
        . $actionBlock
    }

}
```

If a user doesn't specify either switch, the parameter set name will be `Undecided`, and the user will be prompted in the begin block - otherwise we simply use the parameter set name associated with the specified switch.

Since the two switch parameters belong to separate parameter sets, the user can no longer pick both.

Comment: Very clever scripting! I had ParameterSets at first, and went away with them trying to be  "Fancy". Sometimes less is more. Also, saw one of your videos on PSCache, very informative; should do a part 2.